Can 2 rowgroups in Parquet have different encodings for same column?
Let's say there are two row-groups of Parquet, both containing a column segment of type string. Is it guaranteed that both of these will get dictionary encoded or it can vary?
I tried to search for this, closest I got to is this answer.
